# atlas cli not executable in IntelliJ

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, mongodb-atlas

I installed the MongoDB atlas cli following this link https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/cli/stable/install-atlas-cli/ 
I have also added the bin into my environment variables, including `path`, `IntelliJ`. 
And when I type `atlas` in PowerShell everything works fine. 
However, when I use the terminal in IntelliJ, I cannot run `atlas` command. It throws an error

```
atlas : The term 'atlas' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ atlas
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (atlas:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried adding the path for atlas's bin folder into the library in IntelliJ, but it still did not working.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes IDEA can't read system env well, so setting user env variables in IDEA via menu **File | Settings | Tools | Terminal** would be helpful.

[image]